# Heatmap weight change on zoom-out event?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, heatmap

Here my small heatmap of Tallinn with 3 sources:
[image]

As you can see, there is no "red" part on this map example.

But when I zoom-out I get this:
[image]

I need my heatmap to have orange-yellow-green color when you zoom-out, not red.
**How can I achieve that with Heatmap and `google-maps-api` (optionally).**

**Note:**
I did a zoom-out event to change the radius, I think this event can also help me solve this problem, but I do not know what configs should I change:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    heatmap.setOptions({radius:zoomLevel*0.5});
});
```

Comment: I would check out this example: http://output.jsbin.com/rorecuce/1/ Check the source for the getNewRadius function. it is utilized in the initialization and then the zoom change event.

Comment: @Radio this is the answer

Comment: Excellent. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

I worked this out as follows:

```
function getHeatMapRadius(latitudeCoordinate) {
    var distanceInMeter = 3; /* meter distance in real world */    
    
    var meterPerPixel = 156543.03392 * Math.cos(latitudeCoordinate * Math.PI / 180) / Math.pow(2, zoom);
    var radius = distanceInMeter / meterPerPixel;
  
    return radius;
  }
```

Here is the [source](https://medium.com/techtrument/how-many-miles-are-in-a-pixel-a0baf4611fff) for above formula.